# QTreeWidgetItem issue: Items set using setWidgetItem are dispearring after moving

Tags: qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have a bunch of QTreeWidgetItems that have embedded widgets in them that i set using the setItemWidget() function in the QTreeWidgetItem class.

Problem is anytime I move QTreeWidgetItem using drag/drop or any other means the embedded widget I set before disappears.  I've seen around various forums that others have had this same problem (see link below)

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/40500-QTreeWidget-setItemWidget%28%29-item-disappears-after-moving-item

Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by `QTreeWidget`'s implementation. When items are moved within the model, it deletes items at old positions and recreates them at new positions. We need to ensure 3 thinngs:

1. Rescue embedded widget from being deleted when its item is deleted.
2. Attach some information to items so we can track them and choose which widget belongs to an item.
3. Re-insert widget after item is moved.

Here is proof-of-concept implementation. `Tree_widget_keeper_wrapper` ensures 1st objective, `setItemWidget`'s reimplementation ensures the 2nd one, and `rows_inserted` slot ensures the 3rd one. I tested that it works but it should be improved before using in real projects. `Qt::UserRole` should be changed to a configurable role. We should use role that is not used by the model itself. I put all implementation to class declaration to make it more readable but you should separate them in real code.

```
class Tree_widget_keeper_wrapper : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Tree_widget_keeper_wrapper(QWidget* child) {
    _child = child;
    QVBoxLayout* layout1 = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    layout1->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    layout1->addWidget(_child);
  }

  ~Tree_widget_keeper_wrapper() {
    if (_child->parent() == this) {
      _child->hide();
      _child->setParent(0);
    }
  }

private:
  QWidget* _child;

};

class Fixed_tree_widget : public QTreeWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Fixed_tree_widget(QWidget* parent) : QTreeWidget(parent) {
    connect(model(), SIGNAL(rowsInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)),
            this, SLOT(rows_inserted(QModelIndex,int,int)));
  }

  void setItemWidget(QTreeWidgetItem* item, int column, QWidget* widget) {
    QTreeWidget::setItemWidget(item, column, new Tree_widget_keeper_wrapper(widget));
    item->setData(column, Qt::UserRole, all_widgets.count());
    all_widgets << widget;
  }

private:
  QWidgetList all_widgets;

private slots:
  void rows_inserted(QModelIndex parent, int start, int end) {
    for(int column = 0; column < model()->columnCount(parent); column++) {
      for(int row = start; row <= end; row++) {
        QModelIndex index = model()->index(row, column, parent);
        QVariant data = model()->data(index, Qt::UserRole);
        if (data.type() == QVariant::Int) {
          int i = data.toInt();
          QTreeWidgetItem* item = itemFromIndex(index);
          if (item && i >= 0 && i < all_widgets.count()) {
            setItemWidget(item, column, all_widgets[i]);
            all_widgets[i]->show();
          }

        }
      }
    }
  }

};
```

I tested it against `InternalMove` mode and dragging items with mouse. Maybe in some other cases you will need to listen to other model's signals.

Comment: Will try it. It is a shame that 8 years later, there is no simple way to do a fundamental operation, related to a list of items: moving items around. I was expecting it to be the simples thing ever. Imagine a list of chat channels, where when there is a new message in a channel, it comes at the top of the list.